# What does an array look like when it's initialized

Tags: c, arrays

I am working through K&R's C book, and have come across arrays, that I had some questions about:

1. What does an array look like when it's initialized. For example:

```
int word_lengths[10];
```

Does this start as `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`? Or `[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]`. Or something different? Basically I'm trying to conceptualize what an array looks like before it's values are set.

And 2. Is the following required to initialize everything at `0`, or is this done automatically, and it's only used to be explicit in defining the elements in the array?

```
// initialize the array
for (int i=0; i<10; i++ ){
    ndigit[i] = 0;
}
```

Comment: "What does an array look like when it's initialized. For example: `int word_lengths[10];`". What do you mean? That is an _uninitialized_ array. Also, the scope where the array is declared makes all the difference. Is this a local array inside a function, or is it declared at file scope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Automatic arrays are *not* initialized by default. Global and static arrays are initialized to all `0`.

So if you have a program like this:

```
int global_array[10];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int local_array[10];
    // code here
    return 0;
}
```

`global_array` will be initialized as if you'd written

```
int global_array[10] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

But `local_array` contains unspecified values. You can do it with a loop as you show. Reading a value before it's initialized results in undefined behavior.

You can also specify just a single value in the initialization list; it will default all the rest to `0`. So you can write:

```
int local_array[10] = {0};
```

and it's equivalent to

```
int local_array[10] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

None of this is specific to arrays, the same is true for scalar values and structures. Automatic variables are uninitialized, global and static variables are initialized to `0`.